# Как получить имя компьютера в локальной сети по IP?

Tags: android, сеть, kotlin

```
try {
        val socket = Socket()
        val connection = socket.connect(InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, 445), 50)
        val hostName = socket.inetAddress.canonicalHostName
        socket.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {}
```

**socket.inetAddress.canonicalHostName** должен возвращать имя компьютера, но я всеравно получаю IP адрес. Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы? Я в сетях не очень разбираюсь...

**Изменено:**
Рабочий вариант, использование устаревшей библиотеки JCIFS 1.3.17

```
val nbtAddr = NbtAddress.getAllByAddress(ipAddress)
val hostName = nbtAddr[0].hostName
Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Host name - $hostName")
```

**Решение**:
Работает с новой библиотекой jcifs-ng

```
val cifsContext = BaseContext(PropertyConfiguration(System.getProperties())).withGuestCrendentials()
val hostName = cifsContext.nameServiceClient.getNbtAllByAddress(ipAddress)[0].name.name
Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Host name - $hostName, IP - $ipAddress")
```

Comment: попробуйте socket.inetAddress.hostName

Comment: пробовал, он тоже возвращает ip адрес, но это и в документации описано, а вот почему canonicalHostName не работает, не понимаю

Comment: а у того компа вообще имя выставленно?

Comment: Да, я сразу на нескольких пробовал. Да и другие приложения показывают имя каким то образом. Я так понял это имя netbios или как то так, оно ограничено 15 символами. Но я никакое имя получить не могу.

Comment: вот здесь имеется ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842698/inetaddress-getcanonicalhostname-returns-ip-instead-of-hostname

Comment: Без помощи сторонней библиотеки dnsjava не обойтись? Но с ней попробовал Address.getHostName(InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress)) и получил исключение W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown address

Comment: можно попробовать её расковырять и посмотреть, что у неё там внутри. unknown address видимо он всё таки не нашёлся

Comment: Не знаю что он не нашел. Но вот это приложение все находит и как я понял оно тоже использует canonicalHostName https://github.com/aaronjwood/PortAuthority/blob/e4e28a855dd3d7c49c08f4d3c8fd6cf4f6d1ee1f/app/src/main/java/com/aaronjwood/portauthority/async/ScanHostsAsyncTask.java#L139 вот мне бы так :)

Comment: так перенести тот код к себе

Comment: там не сокет, может из-за этого

Comment: Не сокет, точь в точь как там сделал и всеравно ip получил( inet.hostName тоже ip возвращает. Код такой:  val inet = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.173")
val hostname = inet.canonicalHostName
Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "host $hostname")

Comment: хм, ещё вы уверены, что он выставляется именно там, а не через NbtAddress.getAllByAddress(ip);

Comment: NbtAddress это единственное что я не пробовал, но дело в том, что я более новую jcifs либу использую https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng а в ней нету метода getAllByAddress()

Comment: Попробовал старую версию библиотеки jcifs 1.3.17. И в ней удалось получить имя. Спасибо за помощь. Если кто-нибудь знает лучше вариант, напишите пожалуйста, а пока код такой:                        val nbtAddr = NbtAddress.getAllByAddress("192.168.0.173")
            val hostName = nbtAddr[0].hostName
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "host name - $hostName")